# What are `/t.php` GET requests coming to production server?

Tags: php, node.js, security, nginx, server

I have recently published welcome page on my new site hosted on DigitalOcean. I'm using Node JS and nginx.

These requests targeting `/t.php`, POST `/wls-wsat/CoordinatorPortType`, `POST /user/register?`.

Is this a hacking attempt?

Here are nginx logs -

```
80.123.42.103 - - [24/Apr/2018:16:38:54 +0000] "GET /t.php?c=%5B%7B%22k%22%3A%22%5Cb%22%2C%22t%22%3A9874541096%7D%5D HTTP/1.1" 404 144 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0"
80.123.42.103 - - [24/Apr/2018:16:38:54 +0000] "GET /t.php?c=%5B%7B%22k%22%3A%22%5Cb%22%2C%22t%22%3A9874541264%7D%5D HTTP/1.1" 404 144 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0"

80.13.73.224 - - [24/Apr/2018:08:47:10 +0000] "POST /wls-wsat/CoordinatorPortType HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"
80.13.73.224 - - [24/Apr/2018:08:47:10 +0000] "POST /user/register?element_parents=account/mail/%23value&ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"
80.13.73.224 - - [24/Apr/2018:08:47:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3508 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
80.13.73.224 - - [24/Apr/2018:08:47:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3508 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
80.13.73.224 - - [24/Apr/2018:08:47:11 +0000] "GET /rss.php?mode=recent HTTP/1.1" 404 146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely correct!

Someone was scanning for possible vulnerabilities on your system. For instance, the `/user/register` line is related to vulnerability `CVE-2018-7600`, which allows remote execution of arbitrary code if you're using certain versions of Drupal. The `/wls-wsat/CoordinatorPortType` line is likely related to vulnerability `CVE-2017-10271` which allows for takeover of certain Oracle WebLogic servers. As for `/t.php`, I'm unfortunately unable to find any information due to the garbage indexing of modern search engines, but we can reasonably assume that it's related to yet another vulnerability that provides unrestricted root access.

It could be a targeted scan, but it could also be a script kiddie casting a wide net and hoping something sticks. I would assume it's the latter as they appear to be taking a shotgun approach to gaining root access to different kinds of systems.

You probably don't have anything to worry about, but just to be safe I would encourage you to validate that your software is up to date with all security patches and to ensure that none of those requests could be impacting any part of your system (e.g. make sure that if you're running Drupal, it's at least a properly patched version).

Comment: Thanks @B. Fleming